(R) Second-order latent variable CFA not providing standard errors, one variance is negative
I am going to run an SEM model of one second-order latent variable, parental stress, which is made up by two first-order latent variables. Before I run the SEM model, I am verifying the measurement models of the variables I am interested in. When I run the CFA model in R without specifying the higher-order parental stress variable, it runs fine. However, when I specify the higher-order variable, I get the error shown below:

When I examined the summary output of this model, it does not appear to be under-identified, as the model has 133 degrees of freedom. The output is also largely similar to the model that doesn't specify the higher order variable (same model fit indices, for example), but it is missing the scaled estimates and standard error estimates (like the error says). When I examine the variances, it seems that the positive aspects factor has a negative variance. Some of the thresholds are negative, as well, but I do not know if that means anything.
What is going wrong here, and can I fix it? If so, how?


it does not appear to be under-identified, as the model has 133 degrees of freedom

That does not mean it is identified.  Your second-order factor only has 2 indicators.  The 3 pieces of available information from a first-order CFA is the 2 factor variances and their covariances.  You cannot estimate 4 pieces of information (e.g., 2 loadings and 2 residual variances, or 1 loading and 1 factor variance plus 2 residual variances).  The way to identify a 2-indicator construct is to equate their loadings (if you are fixing the factor variance to 1) or set both loadings to 1 (if you are estimating the factor variance).
